Moving Average is not working in Power BI
I have a measure for calculating average days open for open cases-
Average Days open = 
CALCULATE(AVERAGEX('cases',IF('Cases'[Case Status]<>"Closed",DATEDIFF('Cases'[Created On],TODAY(), DAY))))

This is working, but I am trying to create a moving average measure for this. However this shows blank. Can anyone help me regarding this -
MA Avg Days open for open cases = 
VAR NumOfMonths = 12
VAR LastCurrentDate = MAX('Date'[Date])
VAR Period =
    DATESINPERIOD ( 'Date'[Date], LastCurrentDate, - NumOfMonths, MONTH )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE([Average Days open],  Period)
VAR FirstDateInPeriod = MINX ( Period, 'Date'[Date] )
VAR LastDateWithDate = MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )
RETURN
    IF ( FirstDateInPeriod <= LastDateWithDate, Result )


could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?
